# Mock store select in Jasmine karma unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

How do I mock **builderStore** in my unit test? Here is the component in question (BuilderComponent).

```
  constructor(
    private builderStore: Store<fromBuilder.State>,
    private authStore: Store<fromAuth.State>,
    private userStore: Store<fromUser.State>,
    private builderFacade: BuilderFacade
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUser();

    this.builderStore.select('builder').subscribe((builder) => {
      console.log(builder);
      if (builder) {
        this.courseBuffer = builder.courseBuffer;
        this.courseName = builder.course?.name;
        this.selectedCourseContentElementUid = builder.selectedCourseContentElementUid;
        this.isCourseElementSelected = !!this.selectedCourseContentElementUid;
        this.selectedCourseContentUid = builder.selectedCourseContentUid;
        this.selectedCourseModule = builder.selectedCourseModule;
        this.showSelectCardMenu = builder.toolbar.showSelectCardMenu;
        this.showSelectModuleMenu = builder.toolbar.showSelectModuleMenu;
        this.showAddElementMenu = builder.toolbar.showAddElementMenu;
        this.showHelpMenu = builder.toolbar.showHelpMenu;
        this.showNavbarMenu = builder.toolbar.showNavbarMenu;
        this.showCaptions = builder.body.showCaptions;
        this.course = builder.course;
        this.courseContents = builder.course?.modules[this.selectedCourseModule].content;
        if (this.courseContents && this.course) {
          this.courseContentTitles = this.builderFacade.getCourseContentTitles(this.courseContents);
          this.courseModuleTitles = this.builderFacade.getCourseModuleTitles(this.course);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I've tried the following, but the following call `this.builderStore.select('builder').subscribe((builder)` always returns undefined.

```
describe('BuilderComponent', () => {
  let component: BuilderComponent;
  let initialState: IBuilder;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BuilderComponent>;
  const state = TEST_BUILDER_INITIAL_STATE;

  beforeEach(() => {
    initialState = state;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BuilderComponent, MockBuilderNavbarComponent, MockBuilderBodyComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        QuillModule.forRoot(),
        EffectsModule.forRoot(),
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
          metaReducers,
          runtimeChecks: {
            strictActionImmutability: true,
            strictStateImmutability: true,
          },
        }),
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DirectivesModule,
        TooltipModule,
        ModalsModule,
        ShellModule,
        SharedModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: 'preview', component: PreviewComponent },
          { path: 'builder', component: BuilderComponent },
        ]),
      ],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
        BuilderService,
        ToastrService,
        BsModalRef,
        UserService,
        QuillService,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BuilderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('ngOnInit()', () => {
    it('should retrieve values from store', () => {
      const store = jasmine.createSpyObj('store', ['select']);
      store.select = () => of(initialState);
      component.ngOnInit();
      // these values are always undefined
      expect(component['courseBuffer']).toBeDefined();
      expect(component['courseName']).toBeDefined();
      expect(component['selectedCourseContentElementUid']).toBeUndefined();
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    initialState = state;
  });
});
```